# RN CLI error - Failed to build gem native extension, error occurred while installing ffi

Tags: ruby, react-native

When I run `npx react-native projectname`, the project is only created partially.

Now when I run `bundle install` I get:

1. > Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
2. > An error occurred while installing ffi (1.15.5), and Bundler cannot continue.
   > Make sure that "gem install ffi -v '1.15.5' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'" succeeds before bundling.

```console
Using atomos 0.1.3
Using bundler 2.1.4
Using claide 1.1.0
Using fuzzy_match 2.0.4
Using nap 1.1.0
Using netrc 0.11.0
Fetching ffi 1.15.5
Installing ffi 1.15.5 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: █████████████████████s/React
Native/uber/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/ext/ffi_c
█████████████/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.5/lib/ruby/2.7.0 -r ./siteconf20221129-56735-3mfz1o.rb
extconf.rb
checking for ffi_prep_closure_loc() in -lffi… no
checking for ffi_prep_closure_loc() in -llibffi… no
checking for ffi_prep_closure_loc() in -llibffi-8… no
checking for whether -Wl,--exclude-libs,ALL is accepted as LDFLAGS… no
checking for whether -pthread is accepted as LDFLAGS… yes
creating extconf.h
creating Makefile

current directory: █████████████████████React
Native/uber/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/ext/ffi_c
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: █████████████████████React
Native/uber/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/ext/ffi_c
make "DESTDIR="
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
make: *** █████████████████████ Error 2

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in █████████████████████/React
Native/uber/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5 for inspection.
Results logged to █████████████████████/React
Native/uber/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/extensions/arm64-darwin-21/2.7.0/ffi-1.15.5/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing ffi (1.15.5), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install ffi -v '1.15.5' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  cocoapods was resolved to 1.11.3, which depends on
    cocoapods-core was resolved to 1.11.3, which depends on
      typhoeus was resolved to 1.4.0, which depends on
        ethon was resolved to 0.16.0, which depends on
          ffi
```

Yes, I have installed the ffi 1.15.5 (below screenshot) but it is still saying I dont have it

```console
█████████████████████ gem install ffi -v '1.15.5' --source 'https://rubygems.org/ '
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
Successfully installed ffi-1.15.5
Parsing documentation for ffi-1.15.5
Done installing documentation for ffi after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

**Ruby version**: ruby 2.7.5p203 (2021-11-24 revision f69aeb8314) [arm64-darwin21]

**pod** --version: 1.11.3

I am impressed how difficult it is to start a project. Someone please help

Comment: Do you solve the problem. I am getting same error.
An error occurred while installing ffi
(1.15.5), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install ffi -v '1.15.5'
--source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before
bundling

Comment: If you have github project just clone your project at desktop without any spacing in the directory name.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/75146858/13884276
The comment in the above works fine for me for newly project. I myself was perplexed as it was due to a space in folder name and I then cloned again at desktop without any spacing in folder name.

Answer (score 3):

I've been stuck with this problem for an hour. The fix would be initializing your project on a folder directory without space.

Try running npx react-native init on Desktop and it should work fine.

Comment: I confirm this works.

If you encounter the error "An error occurred while installing ffi (1.15.5), and Bundler cannot continue" while running the command npx react-native@latest init AwesomeProject, try initializing your project in a folder directory without spaces. For example, run npx react-native init on the "Desktop" directory, which usually doesn't have spaces in its path. This should resolve the issue.